# Can't update items

Tags: python, podio

I am trying to update items from an app that I created using the app authentication. I first created the items and then I tried to update them but it does not allow me to do so. I am using python and the requests module for doing http requests. I checked and the app allows for the items to be modified by users in the same workspace. Here's the code that I'm using

```
update_item_url = "https://api.podio.com/item/%s" % (cid[1])
add_item_url = "https://api.podio.com/item/app/19860772/"
fields = {"fields":{xxx: [sent],xxx: [opened],xxx: [replied],xxx:[bounced],xxx: [prospects],xxx: [queue]}}
update_item = requests.put(update_item_url, json = fields, 
headers=headers)
```

The error that I get is:

```
403
{"error_parameters":{},"error_detail":null,"error_propagate":false,"request":{"url":"http:\/\/api.podio.com\/item\/11","query_string":"","method":"PUT"},"error_description":"The app with id xxx does not have the right update on item with id xx","error":"forbidden"}
```

Comment: Error ? status code ? anything ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question doesn't seem to include enough information. What do you mean by workspace? What is "app authentication"? What kind of app is this? You should include more info so someone could reproduce in order to get a valid answer. As it currently stands there's not enough info to give you a reasonable answer.

Comment: @Eduardo this is a question about a commercial app called podium. OP should try their official support channels first, because without his API key it is probably impossible to reproduce his problem. Why is he asking random strangers on the Internet instead of people who are paid to support him is beyond me.

Comment: I am asking this here because that's what they referred me to. The Podio support people said they want to keep an open source knowledge base. It's fixed now so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As error says `The app with id xxx does not have the right update on item with id xx`.

Please double check item is from correct app.